# Makefile multiple definition error when adding extern variable

Tags: c, makefile

I'm having trouble with my makefile for a C project (I don't entirely know how to write makefiles...)

Here's a simple tree of my project folder:

```
_ Project
    |_ src
        |_ useful_func.c
        |_ useful_func.h
        |_ program_1.c 
        |_ program_1.h
        |_ program_2.c
        |_ program_2.h
        |_ main.c
        |_ main.h
        |_ ...
    |_ Makefile
    |_ ...
```

And we must have:

- program_1, program_2 and main need useful_func
- main needs the compiled program_1 and program_2

The Makefile I initially wrote worked quite well (added below in the end), until I added in useful_func.h a char* array as extern that both program_1 and program_2 need.

```c
extern const char *foo[] = {..., ...};
```

Now, running `make` gives me this error:

```bash
/usr/bin/ld : 
   /tmp/ccChfBuI.o: path_to_project_folder/src/useful_func.h:7 : multiple definition of « foo »;
   /tmp/ccrNqPsJ.o: path_to_project_folder/src/useful_func.h:7 : defined the first time here 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:29 : program_1] Error 1
```

Despite making sure that each header file had:

```c
#ifndef __HEADER_H__
#define __HEADER_H__
...
#endif
```

So I do not understand why this error occured, especially because all other `#define` seem to be okay, and how to fix this.

Here's my current Makefile (ain't optimal ofc):

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall
LDFLAGS := -lm -lpthread -g

USEFULE_FUNC = $(SRC_DIR)/useful_func.c
PROG_1 = $(SRC_DIR)/prog_1.c
PROG_2 = $(SRC_DIR)/prog_2.c
MAIN   = $(SRC_DIR)/main.c

SRC_DIR := src
TARGETS = prog_1 prog_2 main

.PHONY: all

all: $(TARGETS)

prog_1: $(USEFULE_FUNC) $(PROG_1)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(SRC_DIR)/$@.c $(USEFULE_FUNC) $(LDFLAGS)

prog_2: $(USEFULE_FUNC) $(PROG_2)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(SRC_DIR)/$@.c $(USEFULE_FUNC) $(LDFLAGS)

main: $(USEFULE_FUNC) $(PROG_1) $(PROG_2) $(MAIN) prog_1 prog_2
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(SRC_DIR)/$@.c $(USEFULE_FUNC) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    @$(RM) $(TARGETS)
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: `extern const char *foo[] = {..., ...};` is a definition regardless of the `extern` keyword, not declaration. As you put it in a header, it's then copied to multiple `.c` files, hence multiple definition. You should remove the initialization in the header and initialize the variable in exactly one `.c` file.

Comment: @yeputons Oh, I see. 
However, when I declare it in useful_func.c, neither prog_1 or prog_2 seem to access it (but can access the other functions tho). I don't see how to fix this.

Comment: You _define_ it in `useful_fun.c` as `const char *foo[] = {....}`, and then _declare_ it in `useful_func.h` as `extern const char *foo[];`

Comment: @yeputons It works perfectly! Thank you so much! Looks like I didn't understand how extern variable worked. thx a lot!

Comment: @13-0-G don't forget to upvote/mark the answer as correct below if this is resolved : )

Comment: @code_fodder No worries, will do as soon as I can (because I need to wait 2 days before marking as answered my own reply).

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev Not really because I was using C, not C++. But no worries, someone already answered and it solved my issue.

Comment: Yeah, Stack Overflow adds those comments automatically when you mark two questions as duplicate. I marked them because the root cause was the same. I don't think the language is important because it's the same problem (`extern` var with initializer). Seems like a common question, compilers should add a warning for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question solved by Yeputons in comments:

> `extern const char *foo[] = {..., ...};` is a definition regardless of the `extern` keyword, not declaration. As you put it in a header, it's then copied to multiple `.c` files, hence multiple definition. You should remove the initialization in the header and initialize the variable in exactly one `.c` file.
>
> You define it in `useful_fun.c` as `const char *foo[] = {....}`, and then declare it in `useful_func.h` as `extern const char *foo[];`